# Can you wrap all typescript instance methods into a single custom error handler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

I would like to ensure that, even when it screws up, the event tracking code in my front end never causes an error that impacts the rest of the application. The event tracking is all handled by a few custom classes that deal with labeling evenings and adding the correct properties:

```js
export class TaskTrackerService {

  constructor(private abstractTracker: TrackerService) { }

  // ------
  created(task: Task): void {
    this. abstractTracker.track('Task created', this.taskProps(task))
  }
  // ------
  edited(task: Task): void {
    this.abstractTracker.track('Task edited', this.taskProps(task))
  }

  // ------
  private taskProps(task: Task): EventProperties{
    return {
      id: task.id,
      task_title_char_count: task.title.length,
      task_duration_seconds: task.duration,
      completed: task.done,
      created_at: new Date(task.created_at)
    }
  }
}
```

This class contains logic which could cause errors (e.g. task.created_at is null in the code above) and I want to ensure I catch these before they cause damage.

#### I want to neatly firewall this code

I want to ensure that any errors that are triggered in the tracking class don't propagate anywhere else in the app.

The only way I can think to do this is to add error handling for each individual tracking method as shown below:

```js
export class TaskTrackerService {

  constructor(private abstractTracker: TrackerService) { }

  // ------
  created(task: Task): void {
    try{
      this.abstractTracker.track('Task created', this.taskProps(task))
    } catch(error){
      this.abstractTracker.trackError('Error occurred')
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

### Is there any way to wrap all instance-methods in a single, custom error handler?

To reduce the amount of boilerplate code, I'd like some means to ensure that all of the instanc methods bubble their errors into a class-level handler. Something like this:

```js
export class TaskTrackerService {

  constructor(private abstractTracker: TrackerService) { }

  // I know this isn't possible but...
  catchAll(error){
    this.abstractTracker.trackError('Error occurred')
  }

  // ------
  created(task: Task): void {
    this.abstractTracker.track('Task created', this.taskProps(task))
  }
  ...
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: How about doing it in `abstractTracker.track()`? Maybe add a third callback argument if a class wants to do something special?

Comment: It's not a bad suggestion but the original tracker has logic in it (like extracting properties) and I want to cover any errors that those trigger (edited question to clarify)

Comment: And you'd still be able to do that; `class AbstractTracker { track(what: string, metadata: any, callback: (e: Error) => void) { try { /* everything it does now */ } catch(e) { this.trackError(e, callback) } trackError(error: Error, callback: (e: Error) => void) { this.logOrWhatever(error); if (callback) callback(e); }`

Comment: You can probably just modify the class prototype to do it.  If you'd like to see how, please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NDP1VN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.